# Connect Android Studio with SVN

Tags: android, svn, android-studio

I have an Android project in Eclipse (Windows) synchronized with SVN, I installed Android Studio (Linux) and I need take the same project from SVN.

Comment: Have you tried svn command line tool? http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html

Answer (score 83):

There is a "Enable Version Control Integration..." option from the VCS popup (control V). Until you do this and select a VCS the VCS system context menus do not show up and the VCS features are not fully integrated. Not sure why this is so hidden?

[image: Enable Version Control Integration]

Comment: If you are missing the option, remember to enable the `Subversion Integration` plugin from: `File > Settings > Plugins > mark Subversion Integration`. Then the menu is similar to the one from the screenshot.

Comment: how to install subversion in mac and connect to the android subversion

Answer (score 13):

1. Run Android Studio.
2. From the menu bar, select Android Studio
3. Under IDE Settings, click Plugins and then select Search
   **Subversion Integration**
4. Check SubVersion.
5. Restart Android Studio.

Answer (score 9):

Go to File->Settings->Version Control->Subversion enter the path for your SVN executable in the General tab under Subversion configuration directory. Also, you can download a latest SVN client such as VisualSVN and point the path to the executable as mentioned above. That will most likely solve your problem.

Answer (score 8):

You should open File/Settings/Version Control/Subversion and uncheck 3 options: Use command line client, Use system default Subversion configuration directory and Use system default Subversion configuration directory like http://screencast.com/t/rlh9H2WVpgo

And then go to network tab. Choose SSLv3 instead of All in the field SSL protocols like http://screencast.com/t/l5yw1jqOxV

Lastly, check in or out your source via svn. It works well

Answer (score 6):

Android Studio is based on IntelliJ, and it comes with support for SVN (along with git and mercurial) bundled in. Check http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/version_control.html for more info.

Comment: Whenever I follow those instructions and select my branch under 'merge from...' it presents me with a list of the files and folders under the branch directory which I can select. It will then tell me that the selected directory doesn't match the trunk. I want to select the top level of my branch but it doesn't seem to let me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio we can get the repositories of svn using the VCS->Subversion and the extract the repository and work on the code