# Android Studio missing Subversion plugin?

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to connect my project with my subversion repository but when go to VCS settings, I only see Mercurial listed there.  How can I enable subversion?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679332/connect-android-studio-with-svn

Comment: That post doesn't answer my question.  It says Intellij IDEA comes bundled with subversion integration and you need to enable subversion from settings, but I don't see subversion listed anywhere, only Mercurial.

Comment: did you check the answer on that thread from Jon Cooper? It suggests that a lot of settings are hidden unless you select the "Enable Version Control Integration..." option on the VCS pop up.

Comment: Yes, when I click that the resulting popup only has Mercurial in the dropdown box.  Edited question to show what I see.

Comment: Ah fair enough. That's as far as I can go without being at home as I have no access to anything Android at work. Having just had a look at the Andoid Studio plugins page there doesn't seem to have been any active SVN plugin development for a couple of years - last one was an experimental 1.7 build and that's it. Seems a bit odd.

Comment: One last stab - I presume you've checked out the [IntelliJ help for VCS](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/enabling-version-control.html)? Since Android Studio is based on it it should be farily relevant (although I suppose some options may have been hidden).

Comment: Yes I looked at that but didn't see anything that would help.

Comment: Is the "Subversion Integration" plugin enabled in Preferences > Plugins?

Comment: This was my problem!  Maybe I disabled those upon installation or something?  Who knows.  Thanks.

Comment: Posted as an official answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Please make sure that the "SubversionIntegration" plugin is enabled in Preferences > Plugins.