# best practises for working together on an android project

Tags: android-studio, github

what programs, methods should you use if you want to program with a friend on an android project like a company does?

are there any built in methods? or should you use a third party platform?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect Android Studio with SVN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679332/connect-android-studio-with-svn)

Comment: Your question is a bit broad, but your GitHub tag is a step in the right direction.  Git hosted by GitHub would be a good way for you and your friend to collaborate on an Android app.  If you have a more focused question later, then come back and ask it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two tags already address everything needed to synchronize development between multiple developers. Android Studio for the development and git/Github for sharing a codebase. If you don't know how to use git, Github has [a good getting-started guide](https://help.github.com/categories/bootcamp/) available.

Using git with Android Studio is very easy. Android Studio will usually auto-detect a git repository when you start out, and it has its own [built-in version control tools](https://www.londonappdeveloper.com/how-to-use-git-hub-with-android-studio/) (which are compatible with git). If you don't want to use the built-in tools, you can always use the command line git tools, or [Github's desktop applications](https://desktop.github.com/).

Beyond an IDE and a way to sync code, the rest is up to you. Professional development teams have tons of collaboration tools they use, but any good teams works because of the people, not the tools. You might check out [Trello](https://trello.com/) for tracking to-dos and project details, but there is plenty out there, and the right answer is to try things and see what works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any third party software for this. It's time for you to learn version control. I use git for version control and github/bitbucket for hosting.

Once you have a repo hosted in either, you can add members in that repo.
You can then have a local working copy of the project, preferrably work on different branches based on features or issues. You can then review each other's work before merging to the main branch.

Android studio has built in plugins for git integration.

Now this is just a overview. Read [Git scm documentation](https://git-scm.com/documentation), set up some dummy projects and start exploring the features.